# Postgres backend function not returning expected results in node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am done banging my head against the keyboard on this one.  I'm using a postgres back end, with a node server and pghelper on top.  I have one function working perfectly fine.  See below.

Server side code

```
findAllRegisteredTokensByNotificationId: function(req,res, next){
    try{
        var route = '[GET] - /api/device-tokens/' + req.params.nid;
        Auth.validateHeader(req.headers, route, res, function(){
            if(req && req.params && req.params.nid){
                pgHelper.connectDBAndFindResult('getAllTokensByNotificationId',[req.params.nid], res, function(result){
                    if(result){
                        return res.status(200).json({ data: result.rows, message: 'Retrieved ALL registered device tokens.'});
                    }
                    else{
                        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error finding registered device tokens.'});
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                logger.processError('Error retrieving registered device tokens: Not a valid Request.', res, 500);
            }   
        });
    }   
    catch(err){
        logger.processError('Error finding Device Tokens:' + JSON.stringify(err.message), res,500);
    }
}
```

DB side code

```
-- FUNCTION: stardb.getallregisteredtokensfornotification(integer)

-- DROP FUNCTION stardb.getallregisteredtokensfornotification(integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stardb.getallregisteredtokensfornotification(
integer)
RETURNS SETOF "TABLE(eid text, platform text, device_type text)"
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100.0
VOLATILE 
ROWS 1000.0
AS $function$

BEGIN
FOR eid, platform, device_type IN
SELECT DT.eid, DT.platform, DT.device_type
    FROM notification_token NT JOIN device_token DT
    ON NT.token_id = DT.token_id and NT.notification_id = ($1)
LOOP
RETURN NEXT;
END LOOP;
RETURN;     
END;

$function$;

ALTER FUNCTION stardb.getallregisteredtokensfornotification(integer)
OWNER TO stardb;
```

Then I have another function here that works fine when you run the query on the db, but when called through the node server it gives an unexpected result.

Server side code

```
findAllRegisteredTokensByApplicationId: function(req,res, next){
    try{
        var route = '[GET] - /api/device-tokens/tokens/' + req.params.aid;
        Auth.validateHeader(req.headers, route, res, function(){
            if(req && req.params && req.params.aid){
                pgHelper.connectDBAndFindResult('getallregisteredtokensbyappid',[req.params.aid], res, function(result){
                    if(result){
                        return res.status(200).json({ data: result, message: 'Retrieved ALL registered device tokens per App'});
                    }
                    else{
                        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error finding registered device tokens.'});
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                logger.processError('Error retrieving registered device tokens: Not a valid Request.', res, 500);
            }   
        });
    }   
    catch(err){
        logger.processError('Error finding Device Tokens:' + JSON.stringify(err.message), res,500);
    }
},
```

DB Side Code

```
-- FUNCTION: stardb.getallregisteredtokensbyappid(integer)

-- DROP FUNCTION stardb.getallregisteredtokensbyappid(integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stardb.getallregisteredtokensbyappid(
integer)
RETURNS SETOF device_token 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100.0
VOLATILE 
ROWS 1000.0
AS $function$

DECLARE
r device_token%rowtype;
BEGIN
FOR r in SELECT token_id, token, eid, platform, device_type, app_id 
         FROM device_token where app_id = ($1)
LOOP
    RETURN next r;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
END;    

$function$;

ALTER FUNCTION stardb.getallregisteredtokensbyappid(integer)
OWNER TO stardb;
```

Expected result

```
{
"data": [
{
  "token_id": 15,
  "token": "zzzzzzzzzzzz",
  "id": "dddddddd",
  "platform": "iOS",
  "device_type": "iPhone",
  "app_id": 1
},
{
  "token_id": 16,
  "token": "1234",
  "eid": "BAD-TO",
  "platform": "iOS",
  "device_type": "iPhone",
  "app_id": 1
}
 ], "message": "Retrieved ALL registered device tokens." }
```

Actual result

```
{
"data": {
"command": null,
"rowCount": null,
"oid": null,
"rows": [],
"fields": [],
"_parsers": [],
"RowCtor": null,
"rowAsArray": false
 },
    "message": "Retrieved ALL registered device tokens."}
```

I can provide any other snippets needed.  Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
RETURNS SETOF "TABLE(eid text, platform text, device_type text)"
```

change to

```
RETURNS TABLE(eid text, platform text, device_type text)
```

You either return `setof sometype` or `table(list types)`, when you use double quotes postgres thinks `"TABLE(eid text, platform text, device_type text)"` is a name of a type

Comment: That is the function that is currently working as expected actually.  The error is in the second function. it has
    `RETURNS SETOF device_token`

Comment: hm - I get `ERROR:  type "TABLE(eid text, platform text, device_type text)" does not exist
` trying co compile it - so you indeed have a type with such long and weird name?